# JSQMessagesViewController, RegularTaillessImage not working for images

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to use JSQMessagesViewController and I want to remove the tail from the speech bubbles so they are displayed as regular rounded rectangles. I have this code for the initial setup:

```
let imageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubbleImage: UIImage.jsq_bubbleRegularTaillessImage(), capInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero)
incomingBubbleImageData = imageFactory.incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(incomingColor)
outgoingBubbleImageData = imageFactory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(outgoingColor)
```

and then:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
        let messagesArray = messagesArrayForSection(indexPath.section)
        let message = messagesArray[indexPath.row]
        if message.senderId == senderId {
            return outgoingBubbleImageData
        }

        return incomingBubbleImageData
    }
```

This is working and cutting off the tail for speech bubbles with text, but for images the tail is still there:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: I think you need to create your own media message: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1180

Comment: BTW: Would love to see your solution if you have one!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1168#issuecomment-167153451

In JSQMessageBubbleImageFactory.m change this line:

```
        -(instancetype)init
        {
         return [self initWithBubbleImage:[UIImage 
               jsq_bubbleRegularTaillessImage] 
               capInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this thread:

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1168#issuecomment-167153451

In `JSQMessageBubbleImageFactory.m` change this line:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
//    return [self initWithBubbleImage:[UIImage jsq_bubbleCompactImage] capInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    return [self initWithBubbleImage:[UIImage jsq_bubbleCompactTaillessImage] capInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Comment: - (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithBubbleImage:[UIImage jsq_bubbleRegularTaillessImage] capInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}